# Markov chain: molecules in urns

Tags: probability, markov-chains

[image]

I am struggling to get started on this question.

I think I am confused at what the transition matrix is suppose to represent.

So I know the matrix is going to have this form:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
P_{00}&P_{01}&&...&P_{0M}\\
P_{10}&P_{12}&&...&P_{1M}\\
.&.&&.&.\\
.&.&&.&.\\
.&.&&.&.\\
P_{M1}&P_{M2}&&...&P_{MM}\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Is this sufficient for the transition matrix for general M?

To clear up my confusion, what does $P_{01}$ mean? I think this means that A starts with 0 molecules, and something happened to make it have 1 molecule? (The molecule must have been removed from urn B and put into A, but how do we know urn B has molecules?) How do I find the probability of $P_{01}$?
Also what information allows us to populate the matrix with values?

Comment: I guess you want your transition matrix to be a square matrix and add a column corresponding to state zero as well. Imagine that you have $k$ molecules in urn A and thus $M-k$ molecules in urn B. If you choose a molecules uniformly at random, what is the probability that you chose one from urn A? That immediately gives you the value of $P_{k,k-1}$. Furthermore $P_{k,k+1}=1-P_{k,k-1}$ and you can fill all the values of the transition matrix using this fact and noticing that $P_{k,l}=0$ whenever $k>l+1$ or $k<l+1$ (why?).

Comment: @alezok I am finding it hard to understand the second part of your explanation where you mention $P_{k,k-1}$, can you explain it differently?

Comment: The number of molecules is constant, they are always $M$ in total. $P_{0,1}$ is the transition probabilities from the state $0$ (that is $0$ molecules in $A$ and $M$ molecules in $B$) to the state $1$ (that is $1$ molecule in $A$ and $M-1$ molecules in $B$). When you are in state $0$ and you choose a molecule at random, with probability $1$ is from urn $B$, and then you move it to urn $A$, obtaining state $1$. Hence $P_{0,1}=1$. For the general case see the answer of @JKnecht below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a model by T. Ehrenfest for the movement of molecules in which M molecules are distributed among two urns.

I quote:

If we let $X_n$ denote the number of molecules in the first urn immediately
after the $n$th exchange,  then $\{X_0, X_1,…\}$ is a Markov chain with transition probabilities

$$P_{i, j+1} = \frac{M-i}{M} \:\:\:\:\:\: 0 \leq i \leq M$$

$$P_{i, j-1} = \frac{i}{M} \:\:\:\:\:\: 0 \leq i \leq M$$

$$P_{i, j} = 0 \:\:\:\:\:\: \text{if}\:\:  |j-i| > 1$$

Comment: Isn't P(i,j) = 0 true also for i = j?